# Note 4 screen locked

Tags: settings, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I had finger scanner on my Samsung Galaxy Note 4, but somehow it stopped working. Then with Android Device Manager, I was able unlock the screen with new password, and also registered with new finger scan as well while downloading the new software. I also set notification off on screen as message pop up for same as notification do come on screen before when it was locked during first time it's got locked.

So last night I put DailyMotion on with some current affairs program and slept, but in morning when I tried to unlock the screen it's again not unlocking with new password , I tried again with device manager , the message comes that its already verified password so there is no need for new password, and also with Samsung account but both not working, I'm all stuck as I got all my data, contacts, important pictures in it.

Please do tell me how to unlock or bypass the screen. Please help, as I don't want to do factory reset. Any solution will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:
 
1) Rephrase your questions using better English grammar in order to make it more understandable.
2) (An actual possible solution) Connect your phone to your computer via USB, backup all important data (all data should have already been backed-up via Google Sync but it's good to be safe), then attempt a factory reset.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, to request clarification or improve the grammar of the question you can leave comments or edit the question to improve it once you get enough reputation. Otherwise your answer is fine

Comment: I am unable to leave a comment due to being of low rep. I have run into this issue several times across various StackExchange forums and must say it is very frustrating.  I have used StackExchange for years but have just recently become a member. I am attempting to answer questions in order to raise my rep but cannot due so effectively without a higher rep. Hopefully you can see my Catch 22.